# Google Chrome Extension, new tab focus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs, jquery-tabs

I've been working on an extension for Google Chrome, this is my first attempt.
So far I've been able to run my extension in a new tab, but I wanted to know if there was any possibility to remove the focus from the omnibar/addressbar to some content in the tabbed window.

For Example, I'm implementing an input field or text area, and when a new tab opens, I want the blinking cursor/caret to originate in the said text area, and not the google omnibar.

Any possibility using jquery or any google chrome extension api?

Comment: Do you mean something like `.textarea { outline: none; }`? Or is it something else.

Comment: Did you try the `.focus()` method on the textarea element?

Comment: If you mean that you're overriding the new tab page, it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598778/how-to-steal-focus-from-the-omnibox-in-a-chrome-extension-on-the-new-tab-page Please clarify.

Comment: @lindsay sorry but thats not what I meant.

Comment: @devnull69 the omnibox focus overrides the tab focus

Comment: @Xan Thanks! Thats exactly what I was looking for! Couldn't find it because I couldn't phrase it right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. My solution was to use a "dummy html" file as the new page, and everything this page did was running the following JavaScript code (in an external JS file linked to from the dummy html file):

```js
window.open("the-real-new-tab-page.html")
window.close()
```