# chrome extension: creating new tab and taking focus to page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, focus

trying to make an extension that creating new tab and navigating it to some site and giving some `<input>` to focus.

I check this question but cant solve my problem:
[How to steal focus from the omnibox in a Chrome extension on the new tab page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598778/how-to-steal-focus-from-the-omnibox-in-a-chrome-extension-on-the-new-tab-page)

here is a sample code that I am trying to open a new tab navigating to google and trying to focus on the google search bar.

this is my `content_script.js` try to catch a click on specified web page and specified `<div>` and send a message to my `background.js`

`manifest.json`

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "E-Yaygın Kursiyer Aktarımı",  
    "description": "E-Yaygın Kursiyer Aktarımını Kolaylaştıran Yazılım",  
    "version": "1.0",    
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"],  
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
        ],
        "js": ["jquery.js","content_script.js"]
    }],

    "icons": {
        "16": "images/icons/16.png",
        "19": "images/icons/19.png",
        "38": "images/icons/38.png",
        "64": "images/icons/64.png",
        "128": "images/icons/128.png"
    }
}
```

`content_script.js`

```
$("#kybs_eklenti_edin_btn").hide();
$(document).ready(function (e) {
var host = $(location).attr('hostname');
var url = $(location).attr('pathname');
var search = $(location).attr('search');
console.log(url,"|",host,"|",search);
if (host.indexOf("kybs.com.tr")!=-1){
    if (url == "/yoneticiv2/kursiyerlistesi"){
        $("#tn_logo_holder").click(function(){
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({mesaj: "init_program"}, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            });             
        }); 
    }
}
});
```

`background.js`

```
var openedTab = 0;
var isTabOpen = false;
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.mesaj == "init_program"){
        if (!isTabOpen){
            chrome.tabs.create({selected: true},function(tab){
            isTabOpen= true;
            openedTab = tab.id;
            tabCreated();
            });         
        }else {
            chrome.tabs.get(openedTab, function(tab) { 
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                    chrome.tabs.create({selected: true},function(tab){
                        isTabOpen= true;
                        openedTab = tab.id;
                        tabCreated();
                    });         
                }else {
                    tabCreated();
                }
            });

        }       
        sendResponse("check");
    }

});
function tabCreated(){
    chrome.tabs.update(openedTab,{url:"https://google.com.tr"});

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(openedTab, {file: "jquery.js"},function(tab){
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(openedTab, {file: "jquery.js"},function(tab){
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(openedTab, {file: "inject.js"});
                });
            }else {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(openedTab, {file: "inject.js"});
            }
        });

}
```

`inject.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("buradayız");
    var kursNoInput = document.getElementById("lst-ib");
    kursNoInput.value="840337";
    kursNoInput.focus();        
});
```

and also include a JQuery library.

I am trying to inject javascript with JQuery but it dosent metter. everything works fine but cant take focus from the adress bar to the web page.

second thing if I click on the page that newly created while page trying to load `focus()` works really fine.

I try to search on google resources but cant find any solution and dont know is there a way to taking the focus to the page.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a **manifest.json**, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: What *exactly* is shown in the [various appropriate consoles for your extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982/3773011) when you load and execute your extension?

Comment: @wOxxOm  so what we can do about it. Any suggestion?

Comment: The answers you've linked show some workarounds, try using them. My point is that you can't directly steal the focus from the address bar.

Comment: @wOxxOm I got solution for this issue may I answer my question ?

Comment: Yes, this is actually welcome here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with my solution. idea is simple, when you try to create a new `tab`, by default `selected` attribute is `true`. and when yout create new `tab` it came up to display and its address bar automaticly focused. then you cant steal the focus from `bar` to `page`.

To preventing to focusing address bar you creating new `tab` with attribute `selected:false` like this.

```
chrome.tabs.create({selected: false},function(tab){
                        isTabOpen= true;
                        openedTab = tab.id;
                        tabCreated();
                    });
```

after creating tab than you can update its `link` and `selected` attribute and then you can take focus from address bar with injected javascript.

```
function tabCreated(){
    chrome.tabs.update(openedTab,{url:"https://google.com.tr"});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(openedTab, {file: "jquery.js"},function(tab){
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(openedTab, {file: "jquery.js"},function(tab){
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(openedTab, {file: "inject.js"});
                });
            }else {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(openedTab, {file: "inject.js"});
            }
        });
chrome.tabs.update(openedTab,{selected:true});

}
```

than your `focus()` functions work with no problem.

Comment: This only works if your extension are creating new tab programtically, but when the user clicks the new tab button to create the new tab, you can not steal the focus.

Comment: @ospider you can listen to tabs.onCreate and close it, then open it programmatically.

Comment: @KamranEyyubov yes, but that seems a little awkward