# How to make Google Chrome autofocus input form over search bar?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Whenever I open a new tab it always auto focuses the search bar instead of my beautiful custom made new tab searchbar...

http://prntscr.com/5s38y3

Is there any way to fix this in either my code/script/markup or google settings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome 27: New Tab Page extension can't steal focus from Omnibox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684663/chrome-27-new-tab-page-extension-cant-steal-focus-from-omnibox)

Comment: (so, basically, no, Chrome will not give focus to the page by default)

Comment: how about not by default then?

Comment: "Not by default" - I meant, only the user can change focus. You can't set it up to go to your field when the tab is opened.

Comment: There has to be a way... I mean that must be a setting somewhere right?